# How do you translate "to reel" while fishing?

Tags: single-word-requests

I tried to translate *Reel it in*, but I have no idea to express the idea of pulling the fishing line using the thing we have to turn.

Answer (score 1):

If I trust Reta Vortaro, the 'reel' is *bobenego*, and 'to reel' *bobeni* (though it looks unnatural, because in that case *bobeno* would seem to me *ago bobeni*, and *vindi* actually has the same meaning while *bobeni* seems to be specifically for a reel). *Bobentiri* states it right, in my opinion, so, *En/Al-bobentiru ĝin* could work, eventually.